# Example where $\operatorname{Spec} S^{-1}B$ is neither open nor closed in $\operatorname{Spec} B$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I know that  $\operatorname{Spec} S^{-1}B$ is open in $\operatorname{Spec} B$ with respect to the Zariski topology when $S=\{1,f,f^2,\ldots\}$ for $f\in B$.

However, is this true for every multiplicative subset $S$ of $B$? In what I'm reading I see the example of $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Q}\subset\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$. Is this just because $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Q}=(0)$ and $V(I)$ is always contained in some nonzero prime ideal?

Comment: When you write `\rm Spec B`, then not only "Spec" but also "B" gets de-italicized and also there is not proper spacing. With `\operatorname{Spec}` you get context-dependent spacing, so that for example in $\operatorname{Spec} B$ and $\operatorname{Spec}(B),$ the amounts of space to the right of "Spec" differ without any need to adjust it manually. In LaTeX (as opposed to MathJax, which is used here) you can put `\newcommand{\Spec}{\operatorname{Spec}}` before `\begin{document}` and then just write `\Spec` at each point in the document where you need that. Or even put$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$ Or even put `\newcommand{\Sp}{\operatorname{Spec}}` before `begin{document}` and then type `\Sp B` within the document and you'll get $\operatorname{Spec}B. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks for the tip.

Comment: How did you assert $(0)=V(0)$?

Comment: @Mohan Thanks, silly mistake. I made the edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\Bbb Z$ is a principal ideal domain, every ideal $I\subset \Bbb Z$ is of the form $(n)$ for some integer $n$, which we may take to be non-negative. The prime ideals are exactly given by taking $n$ prime or zero. As the set $V(I)$ consists of the prime ideals containing $I$, we see that $V((n))$ consists of $(p)$ with $p|n$, and only contains $(0)$ if $n=0$. Since the closed subsets of a scheme are exactly given by $V(I)$, this means the closed subsets of $\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb Z$ are the finite collections of $(p)$ for primes $p\in\Bbb Z$ and the whole space. As $(0)$ and its complement $(\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb Z)\setminus\{(0)\}$ aren't in this list, we see that $(0)$ is neither open nor closed.